# VLC Record from Webcam and Save to File - Windows Command Line

Tags: vlc-media-player

I am trying to record a video from a camera and save the recording to a file, using the command line on Windows.

(My comprehension of the vlc documentation is poor at best, and I need some help figuring this out.)

I can get VLC up, displaying my camera, and recording using the command:

```
vlc dshow:// :dshow-vdev="USB2.0 Camera"
```

I tried a number of variations of the command:

```
vlc dshow:// :dshow-vdev="USB2.0 Camera" --sout "#std{mux=ts,access=file,C:\Users\username\Documents\video.avi}"
```

This results in VLC starting but unable to display my camera and no recording taking place. Additionally, no file is created. (I have tried multiple code paths, also.)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

--

VLC version 3.0.6

Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

I got it to work using:

```
vlc dshow:// :dshow-vdev="USB2.0 Camera" --sout file/avi:test.avi --run-time=5
```